# How to delete and element that is rendered in a Web Component

Tags: javascript, native-web-component

In the code snippet if you click the select button it renders a div with a button I'm trying to remove the div when button clicked.

This is how the code flows. In SelectedBtn component handleSelect is fired an object get created and gets pushed to window.selectedItems.items.

Next render is called on selected-products. Then in DeleteButton component render is called then forEach over this.items which is stored in the constructor.

Then the innerHTML is set as a div with a nested delete-button is rendered with the data (I want to delete the whole div & re-render)

User clicks delete button & handleDelete is fired it grabs the id off the event and is stored in a let. Next I call filter on this.items.

If you look a the logs it is removing it from the array this.items but not re-rendering.

```js
class DeleteButton extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.items = window.selectedItems.items;
    this.selectedProducts = document.querySelector('selected-products');
    this.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click',            this.handleDelete.bind(this)));
  }
 // This is what I have tried
  handleDelete(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let productId = e.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    console.log( productId )
    // This is removing the item
    this.items.filter((item) => item.id !== productId);
    console.log('Before', this.items);
    console.log('After filter', this.items.filter((item) => item.id !== productId));
    
    // If I call render below just 
   this.selectedProducts.render()
  }
}
customElements.define('delete-button', DeleteButton);

class SelectedProducts extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.items = window.selectedItems.items
  }

  render() {
    this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
      this.innerHTML = `
      <div style="display:flex; align-items: center; background-color:white; padding:15px; ">
        <delete-button>
          <button data-id="${item.id}" class="delete-btn">
            Delete me
          </button>
        </delete-button>
      </div>
      `;
    });
  }
}
customElements.define('selected-products', SelectedProducts);

class ProductCard extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });

    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =
      `<style>
      ::slotted(div){
        color: #4B5563; 
        font-weight: 900; 
        text-align: center; 
        font-size: 20px; 
      }
      </style>
      ` +
      ` <div style="background: white; margin-right: 15px;">
          <slot name="button"></slot>
          <slot name="img"></slot>
        </div>
      `;
  }
}

customElements.define('product-card', ProductCard);

class SelectBtn extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // This is called with render below
    this.itemsPicked = document.querySelector('selected-products');
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open',
    });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    <button
    aria-label="Select"
    type="button"
    class="pressed"
    data-addbtn="add-btn"
  >
   +
  </button>
    
    `;

    // this.id = this.getAttribute('id');
    // this.name = this.getAttribute('name');
    this.shadowRoot
      .querySelectorAll('button')
      .forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', this.handleSelect.bind(this)));
  }
  // Get data from attributes & store object in
  // an array on window object
    handleSelect(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const itemObj = {
      id: '1',
      name: name,
      qty: 1,
    };

    const item_stored = window.selectedItems.items.find((item) => item.id == itemObj.id);

    if (item_stored) {
      item_stored.qty++;
    } else {
      window.selectedItems.items.push(itemObj);
    }
    this.itemsPicked.render();
  }
}

customElements.define('select-button', SelectBtn);
```

```html
<body>
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; background: lightblue; padding: 10px">
      <product-card>
        <div slot="button">
          <select-button id="1" name="product name"></select-button>
        </div>
        <div slot="img">
          <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px">Select Button</div>
        </div>
      </product-card>
      <div>
        <selected-products></selected-products>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.selectedItems = {
        items: []
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you struggling with a lot of concepts, like we all did, learning this... that is going to take months.

1. Do not store data in the Global Scope. There should be a main `<order-form>` which keeps its state
2. Communication is either done by direct calling methods on `<order-form>` AND/OR with (Custom)Events

#### Walking the DOM

- learn to use the (*standard*) `closest` or use the `closestElement` recursion call to find Elements UP the DOM, **crossing** shadowRoot boundaries

```js
closestElement(selector, el = this) {
    return (
      (el && el != document && el != window && el.closest(selector)) ||
      this.closestElement(selector, el.getRootNode().host)
    );
  }
```

- and DOWN the DOM  you go with the recursive *shadowDive*:

```js
 const shadowDive = (
          el, 
          selector, 
          match = (m, r) => console.warn('match', m, r)
  ) => {
    let root = el.shadowRoot || el;
    root.querySelector(selector) && match(root.querySelector(selector), root);
    [...root.children].map(el => shadowDive(el, selector, match));
  }
```

#### Events

For loose coupling you can send Events UP the DOM tree. And have components listen at common ancestors in the DOM

Think cards on `<poker-table>`; `<playing-card>` Elements *listen* to what the Game dictates.

I have answered many *Event* questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2520800+events

#### bind(this)

`bind` is perfectly valid code, but old-school, since fat-arrow notation gives us lexical scope.
And younger team members won't have a clue what `bind` is doing.

`button.addEventListener('click', this.handleSelect.bind(this));`

Can be written as:

`button.addEventListener('click', (evt) => this.handleSelect(evt));`

Which gets you *lexical scope* for free; and everyone in the team understands what is happening.

Do not tell anyone! I pinched some code from our training database, worked in your lingo, and put it online [here](https://order-form.github.io) Dissect it, read the comments, learn, and always remember there are different ways to skin this cat. (oh, and it has bugs...)

Comment: It needs to be noted that while this fixes the scope issue in the event listener, it can never be removed (which might be irrelevant, but one should be aware).

Comment: also note then that I do use ``bind``, just not with ``this``

Comment: Thanks Danny I will dig into walking the Dom and events. Kinda want to refactor the whole thing anyway. I guess this is my payback for using all that Syntactic Sugar in the past HA HA

Comment: Wow Just inspecting the code now Thanks for all the detail.